# Sum multiple values in a TD

Tags: jquery, sum

I want to get a total and average of some values, but I'm already stuck on starting a jQuery.
This is because the values I want are in the same table.

Can somebody help me to start with this?

My example:
http://jsbin.com/inapey/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var total = 0;
  $('#ritten tr .single_ride').each(function() {
  var ritkm = $(this).html();
  total = total + parseInt(ritkm);
  });
   alert(total);  
});
```

Comment: make that alert outside the each loop

Comment: Hi Dilip thank you for your time, can you maybe have a another look ad my code because i don't get why this should not work. 

http://jsbin.com/inapey/12/edit

Comment: i am not able to getting you.

Comment: So i want for each row a total and average. So when you look at my code, this is the way i thought it should work but it doesn't. I think it has something to do with ".find('.single_ride')". Can you see quickly what i did wrong? http://jsbin.com/inapey/12/edit

Comment: Or is there a way to get it without the span's like in a array? 
<td class="ride_km" style="display:none;">
225,75
</td>